# nginx image_filter ngx_http_image_filter_module alias problem

Tags: nginx, cdn, imagefilter

good day everyone, new time poster, tried looking for a solution to my issue but can't really find anything. I am not a programmer, just a curious person trying to figure things out, so apologies for the non-specific language.

I am setting up a personal space to stock my pictures; I want to access them from the internet no matter where I am.

To reduce load times I am trying to setup the image_filter module in nginx and this is where my problem lies. all the quick guides I've read specify a static alias folder where all images should be stored, but my images will be stored in separate folders. the structure is more or less as follows:

```
/var/www/travel/trip1/image_folder
/var/www/travel/trip2/image_folder
/var/www/travel/trip3/image_folder
```

and so on.
this is important because the site will also serve as backup, and I don't want to 'mix' all the images in one single folder.

so based on the trip* number, the alias should refer to the corresponding subfolder image_folder. no matter what I try, nginx will only serve the image if the static alias is configured:

```
location ~ "^/media/(?<width>\d+)/(?<image>.+)$" {
alias /var/www/travel/trip1/image_folder/$image;
image_filter resize $width -;
image_filter_jpeg_quality 75;
image_filter_buffer 8M;
}
```

is there any way to make the alias 'dynamic'? so if I load the trip1 index page, the images are loaded from /var/www/travel/trip1/image_folder, if I load the trip2 index page they are loaded from /var/www/travel/trip2/image_folder and so on?

thanks in advance.
leo

Comment: hello, anyone? I am stuck and can't really figure it out. ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the remainder of URI and process it, like this:

```
location /static {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/pi/rpiz-site/staticfiles/;

    location ~ \.png$ {
        image_filter resize 200 200;
    }
}
```

Notice this nested location directive part, which actually lets you to capture the remaining of the initial location directive URI, which is the same as you call it "dynamic" alias:

```
location ~ \.png$ {
    image_filter resize 200 200;
}
```

This approach works for my case perfectly: serve static files and if it is a png file, resize it to 200x200px.

Comment: thanks @Konstantin Kozirev, will give it a try as soon as I can!

Comment: @leopaneo If my answer helped, please mark it as the answer. Would be very grateful for that.